# Macbook Finder Won't Start After Changing Home Directory

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, macbook-pro

I bought another Macbook Pro. It's a second hand machine but as good as new with 16GB of RAM out of the box - mid 2012 I5.

When I came home, I decided to change every information in Users & Groups. After changing those and restarting, the Macbook won't start its Finder.

Is there any way to fix this without reinstalling a new OS? (I'll install later if it's the only way). Take note that the screen shot is from my personal Macbook Pro.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I urge you to completely erase the entire drive and reinstall the OS cleanly. Boot from a recovery partition or Internet Recovery or another partition or an external drive if you need to back up any files first before you wipe your drive.

It's extremely poor computing hygiene to try to just live in the used OS install left behind by the previous owner. Who knows what dangers and problems are lurking in that dirty lived-in environment.

That said, if you ever screw up one user account to the point that it's unusable and don't have another admin account to fix it from, you can use the following trick to create a new admin account on the system:

1. Reboot into Single User Mode by holding down Cmd-S at boot.
2. Follow the on-screen instructions to make the boot volume writable.
3. `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`
4. `reboot`
5. When your machine reboots, it will run the Setup Assistant that you normally see on the first boot of a new Mac or after a clean OS reinstall. Use that Setup Assistant to create a new local admin account.
6. At the end of the Setup Assistant process, you will be automatically logged in as the new admin account you created. You can either just choose to live in that account and delete the broken account, or you can spend time trying to un-break the directory settings you screwed up for the other account.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply change the information.  You have to create new user accounts and delete the old ones.

But I agree with Spiff.  You should do a full re-install.  Use your other mac to create a bootable USB of Sierra (or older if preferred) and start anew.  Slower, longer process, but a wise one.  You never know if the previous owner had some kind of malware installed (deliberately or not).

Good luck!